# How to I make it mandatory that documents in my SharePoint library are saved before opening?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word

Afternoon,

I have a number of word documents saved in a sharepoint library that we are encouraging people to use a project templates.  However, I do not want poeple to be able to save to the document library that they are saved in or be able to edit the document saved in the library.  Essentially, when they click to open the document they are promted to save.  Does anybody know how I go about doing this?! We dont want our document folder cluttered with over peoples work!

Comment: Just give people Read access only. Or do they need to edit files from time to time? If you download a document from the library to your desktop, when you open it are you still prompted to save it?

Comment: Hi Mihail,The only people that will ever need to edit the files saved in the document library will be my team who will have full control.  When they download a copy they can do whatever they please:)

Answer (score 2):

```
I have run into this issue myself. In my case I had the following scenario:

Initially, my web application had 'Browser File Handling' set to 'Strict' (which is the default when creating a web application)
Created a site collection, then a custom document library, and saved it as a template
Created a new document library using the template
Changed the web application 'Browser File Handling' to 'Permissive'
Found that I still was prompted to save PDF files before opening in the document libraries created with my template. Document libraries created with the out-of-the-box templates worked as expected.
```

I am sure there are more scenarios where this issue would surface, perhaps saving a web as a template before changing 'Browser File Handling'. Although I should do more testing for a complete list of scenarios, I needed to find out what was the cause. So I investigated.

Each Document Library in SharePoint 2010 actually has a property titled BrowserFileHandling that is set based on the BrowserFileHandling selection at the Web Application level. In the scenario I described above, I have found that the inheritance of this property does not always behave as you would expect.  Using PowerShell (you could also use the object model) you can take a look at the BrowserFileHandling property at the Document Library level as this is not exposed in the UI.
Look at the following link:
    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/95a9f8fa-3da6-4bb7-9983-2102910ff4aa/sharepoint-2010-prompts-to-save-pdf-documents-when-opening?forum=sharepointadminprevious